# How can I use javascript to disable Office botton when I open a Word document on explorer?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, vsto, ribbon

I want to disable the "save as" button in MS Word, when a document is opened in IE. I want to use JavaScript to implement this function.

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
word.Application.CommandBars("File").Controls(5).Delete();
word.Application.Visible = true;
```

But this function doesn't work. What can I do?  I'm sorry for my poor English.